# Why is $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ a group of interest?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology

Other than "a natural generalization of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$" (or any sort of better understood $SL(2,?)$" (such as $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ which is acts isometrically on the upper half plane which lives in the crossroad of many fields), is there any direct reason why one would want to understand this group (and its cohomology ring)?

(In case you're wondering, I'm looking at this paper by Adem and Naffah: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9503230.pdf)

Thanks in advance, and please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Have you tried going down the reference rabbit hole? I briefly tried to navigate through some of the references and the references' references, and there seem to be hints of something interesting happening. Page 80 of Trees by Serre discusses this a bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you mean Cor 2 on that page? I have studied that and it just explains why $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ is the amalgamated product of 2 copies of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ with respect to this subgroup $\Gamma_0(p)$, which follows by a straightforward argument concerning the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ on the $SL_2$-tree of lattices. I'm not looking for this. What I'm looking for is the reason why $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ is studied to start with, and example usages of the cohomology ring of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$.

Comment: (For example, the "original" motivation, or what not). I understand that one could easily justify the study any $SL(2,?)$ for the sake of research completeness, but I'd like to see particular usage of $H^*(SL(2,\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$.

Comment: Sure, I just meant that there's some extra discussion about these sorts of things around that theorem. Some bits about discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, some bits about presentations, some about congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ... that's why I mentioned the reference rabbit hole and 'hints of something interesting happening.'

Comment: Hm, right. I'm aware of the scattered pieces that you mentioned, and was hoping for a more "direct motivation". But perhaps, there's really no satisfactory answer for this now. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: You piqued my interest, so I did some asking around. For motivations in number theory, I was pointed to these sources:

https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/28.Integration/paper.pdf
https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/69.DV1/DV-dmj.pdf
https://services.math.duke.edu/~dasgupta/papers/DasguptaPhdThesis.pdf

I was also told that understanding this group as a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ yields a nice negatively curved space that relates to geometry/algebraic groups/number theory.

Comment: And here's a nice survey on buildings. This'll be my last comment! http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/talks/BruhatTits.pdf